# Where to find weblink in developer project?

Tags: actions-on-google

Hi does anyone know where can I find the weblink for google action? On the [documentation page](https://developers.google.com/actions/discovery/directory#use-the-assistant-directory-weblink) it says "You can obtain the weblink from your developer project's **Overview** page." but I don't see it on console.developers.google.com or console.actions.google.com. Any help? or is Google still updating the documentation and consoles?

Comment: Yes, Google is still updating the consoles. Since this weblink is to link to your Action in the Directory Assistant (which is where all of the published Actions are placed in the Google Assistant interface), I would guess your app needs to be published for you to have this link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This feature, although announced, is still rolling out. We should expect it within a week or so. (Hopefully).